# JQuery animation behave strange on fadeOut

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div which I axpect to be closed in animated way. How whenever I try, it try to dissaper in strange way. I dont know even by which words I should google my problem.

This is my html code.

```
       #{ifErrors}
            <div id="warningDiv">
                <h2>&{'opps'}</h2>  
                <ul id="ulwarningDiv">
                    #{errors}
                       <li>${error}</li>
                   #{/errors}
                </ul>
                <span class="warning_close"> </span>
            </div>
        #{/ifErrors}
```

This the jquery event :

```
$('span.warning_close').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').animate({"width" : 0, "height" : 0, "opacity" : 0, "border" : "none", "padding" : 0}, 600);
});
```

Comment: You maybe better off using `fadeOut()` unless you need it to animate in a certain way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FadeOut**

demo - [**fadeOut**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/bpqec1yw/)

```
$(this).closest('div').fadeOut()
```

**Opacity**

demo - [**Opacity**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/bpqec1yw/1/)

```
$(this).closest('div').animate({"opacity" : 0}, 600);\
```